# Redirect back to contact.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `form.js` code. Please help me to redirect back to `contact.html` form after *successful* or *error* message.

```
$(function() {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');
      jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, val) {
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function() {
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');

        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
        }
      });
    } //else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);

    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function() {
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Please Wait Sending ...');
    });

    var formdata = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: formdata,
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = whatever url you want to send the user to
```

Comment: but where should I input that line? After which code block ?

Comment: last thing in your submit button handler, I'd imagine

Comment: Can you please tell the proper code block here ? just by editing that specific block ?

Comment: @zbnrg No, the OP wants it after a success or error message, so at the end of `after_form_submitted`.

Comment: @sarthak That is for you to figure out. However if you do need our help, post a completely working question rather than a code snippet. Did you not write this code?

Comment: @zbnrg I'll try it.. Thank You so much friend !

Comment: oh sorry i misread, it would be the last line in each of the conditional of the after_form_submit.  But you may want to delay a second or so so the message shows beforehand w/setTimeout (i believe jquery objects have delay functions also)